# IIS Server hosting API and Angular 2 app No CORS sent

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-webapi

TLDR: 1 Server, IIS, two sites, missing CORS Headers on preflight response

```
> http://myserver:88   // This is my angular site
> http://myserver:8888 // This is my .NET CORE API
```

Background:

I've developed an ASP.NET CORE API and an Angular web application.
I have them hosted on the same server with IIS. They are two different 'Sites'.

I am having a CORS issue. I am force sending the response header like so....

[image]

Now in my login endpoint I need custom headers. So a preflight response is needed.. 
chrome shows this..

[image: I get the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header]

Then the very next call shows this.

[image]
[image]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

This is how my cors set up looks in the API.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        string[] origins = new [] { "http://myServer:88" }; // PORT TO HOSTED ANGULAR SITE

        services.AddCors(options => {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin", builder =>
                builder.WithOrigins(origins)
                    .WithMethods("GET", "POST")
                    .WithHeaders("accept", "content-type", "origin", "username", "password")
                    .AllowCredentials()
                );
            });

        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

Comment: I wrapped my endpoint in a try catch and in the catch returned exception e.  The database connection was not correct and threw an error. 
This exception was somehow triggering the CORS error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was nothing wrong with my CORS setup. It was due to an exception being thrown in my endpoint. I hope this helps others.